# How should you decide whether to post on 'Physics.stackexchange.com' or on 'Physicsoverflow.org'?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

What is the main difference between questions asked on The 'Physics StackExchange' website, and those asked on the 'Physicsoverflow.org' website - it seems to me that 'Physics Overflow' is more detailed higher level Physics, but I may be wrong.

Comment: PO is not part of the SE network, and hence off-topic. Phys.SE allows both high-level and low-level questions, cf. e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5922/2451) and [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5697/2451) meta posts.

Comment: You're right - PhysicsOverflow is focused on graduate-level+ physics, but there are some other minor differences - PhysicsOverflow functions more of a community and is both more liberal and meritocratic than PSE. See e.g. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1608/

Comment: My understanding is that, in addition, PO has no expectation of civility and relatively weaker moderation. (Which is kind of saying the same thing)